# Postgis - Find records that each contain a point within a circular area

Tags: postgis, point, intersection, overlapping-features, circle

[image]

I have a few tables:

- hubs
- coverage_areas
- jobs

---

- Jobs have a lonlat (st_point) column
- Coverage areas have a lonlat (st_point) column and a radius (integer).
- Hubs can have multiple coverage areas.

According to the image above, there are multiple coverage areas colored blue, and a single job colored orange.

Question:  How would I query for all hubs where the job lonlat point is within any one of their coverage areas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  The tour states that there should be only one question per question, but here you have asked 2 questions.  Please **[edit]** your question to focus on just one question.

Comment: It also appears that you have somehow created two accounts - see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them, so that you can get notifications and are able to edit your question directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a query like this:

```
SELECT * from jobs
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT c.id as cid, s.id as sid, s.geom as geom, c.distance as distance from coverage_area as c
    OUTER JOIN stations as s
    on s.id = c.id) as cs
ON ST_DWithin(jobs.geom, cs.geom, cs.distance)
WHERE cs.cid is not null
```

(Untested...)

Here I'm doing it in two parts, first joining the **stations** and the **coverage areas** and then selecting with `ST_Intersects` for the **jobs**.

You could make it a bit simpler by changing the sub-query into a view of all coverage areas, including the buffered distance around the stations, and then you have a single join on the 'intersects' condition.

Comment: Why use ST_Buffer? It's both expensive and imperceptive. Always use ST_DWithin for a distance-based query, which is much cheaper (can use an index) and exact.